# How to make sure only one [0,1] AsyncTask is ever running?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

currently I have this simple demo application. It has a button that once clicked, creates a new AsyncTask that waits 3 seconds before generating a random name and displaying it

[image]

However, if you click the button multiple times in quick succession, new AsyncTasks get queued behind the first one - executing serially.

Is it possible to disable the queue feature,

## **such that the last AsyncTask is the only one that gets executed (and will start immediately - thus canceling any AsyncTask before it)**

Below is the code I currently have, thanks for any help

```
package com.example.www.android_async_task;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public Button   NAME_BUTTON;
    public TextView NAME_DISPLAY;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NAME_BUTTON  = (Button)   findViewById(R.id.bt_name_button);
        NAME_DISPLAY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name_display);

        NAME_BUTTON.setOnClickListener(name_button_listener);
    }

    public View.OnClickListener name_button_listener = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "new CustomTask().execute();");

            new CustomTask().execute();
        }
    };

    public class CustomTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "SystemClock.sleep(3000);");

            SystemClock.sleep(3000);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
        {
            String[] names = {"Frank L. Lane",
                              "Kevin C. Payne",
                              "Barbara R. Junker",
                              "Nicholas S. Jones",
                              "Ralph M. Crump",
                              "Loretta T. Francis",
                              "Alisha M. Williams",
                              "Daniel D. Hardy",
                              "Chadwick M. Gantz"};

            String name = names[new Random().nextInt(names.length)];

            Log.d("MainActivity", "NAME_DISPLAY.setText(name);");

            NAME_DISPLAY.setText(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: simple solution is to disable button click once it clicked and enable it after generating name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple method is to declare a global variable `boolean isAsyncRunning=false`

```
 CustomTask customTask;  // globalVariable

@Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "new CustomTask().execute();");

           if(!isAsyncRunning){

             customTask= new CustomTask();
             customTask.execute();
             IsAsyncRunning=true;
      }
      else{
           if (customTask != null && customTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
                            customTask.cancel(true);
           customTask= new CustomTask();
             customTask.execute();
             isAsyncRunning=true;

       }
    }
```

and in postexecute make it false

```
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
    {
        String[] names = {"Frank L. Lane",
                          "Kevin C. Payne",
                          "Barbara R. Junker",
                          "Nicholas S. Jones",
                          "Ralph M. Crump",
                          "Loretta T. Francis",
                          "Alisha M. Williams",
                          "Daniel D. Hardy",
                          "Chadwick M. Gantz"};

        String name = names[new Random().nextInt(names.length)];

        Log.d("MainActivity", "NAME_DISPLAY.setText(name);");

        NAME_DISPLAY.setText(name);
       isAsyncRunning=false;
    }
```

If your CustomTask extends AsyncTask you could write :

```
public void execute(){
    super.execute();
    isAsyncRunning= true;
}
```

so you don't have to manually set the boolean value.

Comment: Is it possible for the last AsyncTask is the only one that gets executed (and will start immediately - thus canceling any AsyncTask before it)

Comment: where would `customTask` be placed? In `MainActivity` or `OnClickListener`

Comment: `CustomTask customTask;`  this line in MainActivity above oncreate

Answer (score 2):

try this:

Here as soon as Async starts, disable button click, and after completing name generate, enable it again

```
public class CustomTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

       @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            NAME_BUTTON.setClickable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "SystemClock.sleep(3000);");

            SystemClock.sleep(3000);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
        {
            String[] names = {"Frank L. Lane",
                              "Kevin C. Payne",
                              "Barbara R. Junker",
                              "Nicholas S. Jones",
                              "Ralph M. Crump",
                              "Loretta T. Francis",
                              "Alisha M. Williams",
                              "Daniel D. Hardy",
                              "Chadwick M. Gantz"};

            String name = names[new Random().nextInt(names.length)];

            Log.d("MainActivity", "NAME_DISPLAY.setText(name);");

            NAME_DISPLAY.setText(name);
            NAME_BUTTON..setClickable(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check before start AsyncTask is already running or not.if its not running  execute AsyncTask. Another way after click  disable button in onClick then enable button again in onPostExecute(AsyncTask). so that user can able click only one time.During the execution user cant click button.

```
   CustomTask customTask;    //declare global
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
         customTask=  new CustomTask();
         // 
         if(customTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) 
         {
          customTask.execute();
         }          
        }
```

Comment: Your answer is completely unrelated to my question